# Python Loop Controls Exercise

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean-logic

I just started studying python on hyperskill for the past few weeks.

Here's the scenario:

> Write a program that reads from the console integers (one in a line) until their sum is equal to 0. Immediately after that, it should display the sum of the squares of all the entered numbers.
>   It is guaranteed that at some point the sum of the entered numbers will be equal to 0. After that, reading is not necessary to continue.
>
> In case the first integer equals to 0, also stop reading values from the input. Print out 0 instead of the sum of the squares.
>
> For example, we are reading the numbers 1, -3, 5, -6, -10, 13. At this point, we have noticed that the sum of these numbers is 0 and output the sum of their squares, not paying attention to the fact that there are still unread values.

```
num = int()
listtrigbreak = []
listsquares = []

sumtrig = 0
sumsqua = 0

while sumtrig != 0: # until sum of trig is not 0, 
  num = int(input())     #accept numbers

  if num == "0": # while first input is 0,
    print(0) # print 0
    break    # and break the loop


  listtrigbreak.append(num)   # append num to listtrig
  sumtrig += sum(listtrigbreak) # add sum of list to sumtrig


  for x in listtrigbreak: # for each number in listtrigbreak
    squared = x ** 2     # convert each to squares, save variable
    listsquares.append(squared) # add squared to listsquq
    sumsqua = sum(listsquares)  # sum of squares in listsqua

else:
  print(sumsqua)
```

I can't even get past the first while loop. Whenever I run it, it skips the entire while loop and heads over to this:

```
else:
  print(sumsqua)
```

I've really had a hard time with boolean logic from the start. I need explanations.

Comment: `while` does not mean "until".

Comment: I'm not sure why you're surprised that it skips the first `while` loop. The condition is `sumtrig != 0`, and you just finished initializing `sumtrig` to `0`. You're also going to have trouble later on, when you make `num` a number and then check whether it matches a string.

Comment: Your code within the `while` loop will only execute **as long as** thecondition in your while statement `sumtrig != 0` is `True`. In plain English this reads like so: _as long as sumtrig is NOT zero do the following..._ Since you initialised `sumtrig` to be `0` your condition `sumtrig != 0` will evaluate to `False` and Python will just skip over your entire while loop.

Comment: Wow, I guess I really have to backtrack and study more on these loops and booleans. My logic with these appears to be pretty off. Thanks a lot for your insight guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other comments already pointed out, the while loop is a bit tricky since you initially declare the variable to 0. You could use a boolean switch that controls the while loop, like so:

```
input_integers = []
stop = False

while not stop: # So while we should keep asking user input...
    num = int(input())

    input_integers.append(num)

    if sum(input_integers) == 0 and len(input_integers) > 0:
        print('done')
        stop = True
```

Now add the other functionalities in it, and you're done.